# How to select JSON arrays with D3.js with . operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, dot-operator

Im using D3.js to create a bar chart from a JSON file. I want the user to filter through different years and different countries. I can't seem to figure out how to select the different arrays from the JSON file.

My JSON is set up like this: (which could be wrong)

```
var NL = [
    j1996 = [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    j1997 = [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
    j1998 = [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
]

var BE = [
    j1996 = [52317, 17395, 39273, 47170, 39441],
    j1997 = [35267, 13331, 15193, 15299, 13005],
    j1998 = [15576, 20643, 14284, 25796, 13343]
]
```

Then I have buttons that load the data from the different years:

```
d3.select("#button1996")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(j1996);
    })
d3.select("#button1997")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(j1997);
    })
d3.select("#button1998")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(j1998);
    })
```

bars function

```
function bars(data) {

max = d3.max(data)

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, height])    

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(0, data.length))
    .rangeBands([0, width], .2)    

var myChart = d3.select("#chart")

var bars = myChart.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .data(data)

//enter
bars.enter()
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .style('fill', '#C64567')
    .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr('x', function(d,i){ return xScale(i); })
    .attr('height', 0)
    .attr('y', height)
}
```

This works

```
    d3.select("#button1996")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(NL[0]);
    })
```

How can I toggle between the NL and BE arrays (in the future more) but remember the year that is selected last?

Comment: what does your 'bars' function look like ? You need to add more code ...

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it! I've added the bars function and rephrased the question slightly at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you try to have `NL` to be both an array and an object.

Your declaration

```
var NL = [
  j1996 = [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
  j1997 = [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
  j1998 = [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
]
```

gives the same result as

```
var NL = [
  [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
  [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
  [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
]
```

i.e., it is an array of arrays. So no hope to be accessing NL.j1996 this way (to be exact, you are also afecting each array to the corresponding *global variable* `j199x`).

If you want to use `NL` as an object, the syntax is the following:

```
var NL = {
  j1996 : [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
  j1997 : [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
  j1998 : [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
}
```

Then `NL.j1996` won't create an error anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
var NL = [
    j1996 = [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    j1997 = [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
    j1998 = [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
]

var BE = [
    j1996 = [52317, 17395, 39273, 47170, 39441],
    j1997 = [35267, 13331, 15193, 15299, 13005],
    j1998 = [15576, 20643, 14284, 25796, 13343]
]
```

That is wrong format, NL and BE should be objects containing arrays like so :

```
var NL = {
    j1996 : [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    j1997 : [25267, 31331, 35193, 35299, 23005],
    j1998 : [25576, 30643, 35484, 35796, 23343]
}

var BE = {
    j1996 : [52317, 17395, 39273, 47170, 39441],
    j1997 : [35267, 13331, 15193, 15299, 13005],
    j1998 : [15576, 20643, 14284, 25796, 13343]
}
```

As it is an object you cant call it like this :

```
d3.select("#button1996")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(NL[0]);
    })
```

You have to do :

```
d3.select("#button1996")
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        bars(NL['j1996']);// or 
        //bars(NL.j1996);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout JSON is in a wrong format.
Use something like that. You can access to your data with :

```
 data.NL[0], etc
```

Your JSON should have the following format :

```
{
"NL": [{
    "j1996": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    "j1997": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    "j1998": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441]
}],
"NL": [{
    "j1996": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    "j1997": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441],
    "j1998": [20317, 27395, 29273, 27170, 19441]
}]

}
```

Don't forget to validate your JSON with a tool like http://jsonlint.com/.